# Installing rvm on Linux Mint KDE

Tags: rvm, linux-mint

I'm having a hard time getting rvm to install on Mint. I tried the instructions at:

https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/

The first step proceeds without incident. However, when I try to run source ~/.bash_profile, I get an error message stating that no such directory exists. I can restart the terminal, but it still says that "The program 'rvm' is currently not installed...."

A .rvm directory in now present in my home directory and the binary is there. I'm suspecting that this means that I need to add something in my .bashrc (or somewhere else) to tell the OS where to look for executables. But I'm still a little new at Linux and am uncertain where exactly it needs to go or what it should be.

Answer (score 1):

The Answer in the same site:

```
echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

`[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" #` Load RVM function

Looks like this needs to be tacked onto the end of the **.bashrc file** if it isn't present.